# Is cheating at schools/universities' exams haram?

Tags: halal-haram, school, cheating

I know that cheating is a bad act, but I’d like to know what the ruling of Islam is about it?

In fact, is it a haram (forbidden) act or it is solely a Makruh (disapproved) practice?

Is there any tradition in regards to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cheating is a kind of "lie". The Qur'anic verses (ayahs) and traditions prohibiting "lie" are free from any stipulations so the word "lie" embraces all kinds of "lie" whether it is a verbal lie or a written lie or a practical lie especially when it results in trampling others' rights.

> **إِنَّما يَفْتَرِي الْكَذِبَ الَّذينَ لا يُؤْمِنُونَ بِآياتِ اللَّهِ وَ أُولئِكَ هُمُ الْكاذِبُونَ**
>
> Verily, those who forge lies they are Those who do not believe in
>   Allah's Signs and Revelations and they are Indeed the liars. (Al-Nahl
>   105)
>
> ---
>
> **إِنَّ اللَّهَ لا يَهْدي مَنْ هُوَ كاذِبٌ كَفَّارٌ...**
>
> ... Indeed Allah does not guide someone who is a liar and an
>   ingrate.(39:3)

Imam Muhammad al-Baqir (a.s.) says:

> “Certainly Allah has created the lock for every evil and the key to
>   all these locks is drinking wine. But lying is worse than drinking.”

**Additionally**, there is no difference among the scholars about prohibition of cheating. *To find out about it in details please visit this [LINK](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1411)*.

Comment: would you plz indicate a verse or tradition about the matter which you mentioned?

Comment: or at least is can you quote any matter from a famous scholar?

Answer (score 1):

**Cheat and Trick are forbidden in Islam** and blameworthy not characterized by the believer!

> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏
>   من حمل علينا السلاح، فليس منا، ومن غشنا، فليس منا‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه
>   مسلم‏)‏‏)‏‏.
>
> The Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) said, "He who takes up arms
>   against us is none of us; and he who cheats us is none of us."
>    [[Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/69).

This applies to all Cheats and trickery in any field and in the right of any person as evidenced by the words of the modern.

Comment: it is a nice response, but do you think if there is any tradition about cheating (at school)? or solely it has mention in general?

Comment: @السید____علی the thing is, cheating is considered shortcut to earning money without working hard, even in your case, so I support this answer.